# RavenDB across multiple drives?

Tags: ravendb

Is it possible to store a Raven DB across multiple local drives?
We have a drive size limitiation.

I see 2 possible scenarios:

1. One database spread across D: & E:
2. Two databases.  One stored on D: and the other on E:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure each database to be on a specific drive. However one database must be in one location.

Here is how to do this when creating the database:

[image]

Also see this from the documentation:

> The structure of RavenDB directories cannot be changed except locations of temporary files for documents and indexes by setting appropriate configuration options.
>
> However, you can store any RavenDB data in different locations by
>   defining junction points (Windows) or mount points (Linux).

https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/4.0/Csharp/server/storage/directory-structure#storing-data-in-custom-locations